# Converting sonar ranges to laserscan message

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

In my project i should do mapping and localization using only ultrasonic sensor and IMU. Most of mapping packages in ros use [laserscan message](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html), the ultrasonic sensor return a [range message](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html).

I am using 10 HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor.
ROS kinetic ubuntu 16.04.
MPU-6050.

How can i construct a laser scanner message using the different readings sonar sensor ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265113/converting-sonar-ranges-to-laserscan-message/) by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-06-29**:
Possible duplicate: http://answers.ros.org/question/237478/can-i-localize-with-imprecisenoisy-sonar-sensor/

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-06-29**:
This is not a duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's one option: http://wiki.ros.org/range_sensor_layer

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2017-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-06-29**:
thank you very much, I hope this package can help me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here i convert just one range message to laser scan: https://github.com/RiccardoGiubilato/ros_autonomous_car. Please take a look at the "sonar_to_laser" node,  hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [RiccardoGiubilato](https://answers.ros.org/users/32342/riccardogiubilato/) with karma: 76 on 2017-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-10-24**:
Thank you very much for your help

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-10-30**:
I don't think that this is a good idea. Also the question is: Why?

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-11-02**:
@Humpelstilzchen do you have any other proposal to solve the problem ??

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-11-03**:
See the answer of David Lu.